# Tracing dependencies in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, view

In a complex database, Postgres refuse to alter a view since many rules, and many other views depends on it.

I can drop the view with all its dependencies with `DROP CASCADE`, but how will I recreate these views afterwards? It's not so easy, since even if I know that both `V` and `U` depends on the view I want to alter I can't just create them however I want. If view `V` depends on `U`, I must create `V` first and only then create `U`.

How can I trace which other views and rules depend on a certain view, so that I'll be able to alter it in the easiest way? I also want to generate a script so that everyone would be able to alter the view with my script, any easy way to generate that?

Comment: In the future source your objects in version control. That way you at least know what objects you have and you can recreate them in an empty database and do a object dump after that you could do a diff to see what your prod database has or doesn't have compared to the source control.  This assumes you maintain your version control system as part of a release process.

Comment: I need to alter a live database of a client, I don't understand how schema under version control would help me in this respect. I can figure out the schema.

Comment: Ah I see. I assumed it was an in house database system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how well this will work for you, but the least laborous way would probably be DROP CASCADE and use [apgdiff](http://apgdiff.startnet.biz/) to re-create the dropped views:

1. Run `pg_dump -s -f old_schema.sql` to create a schema dump -- which includes all views etc.
2. Run `DROP VIEW x CASCADE`
3. Run `pg_dump -s -f new_schema.sql`
4. Run `apgdiff new_schema.sql old_schema.sql > restore.sql` -- create a script to restore the old schema in the database.
5. `psql -f restore.sql`

Unfortunately this means that your database will be missing these views for a window of time, so you probably have to take it offline for maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the system table [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html) to get the dependencies.

Comment: Can you please refer me to usage example? It is easier to figure it out with an example.